# How to use ui png images as ui elements in the editor?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a package with all kind of png ui's like buttons and more.
The package is in a folder under Assts.

[image: PNG ui's]

and I want to use it for example as background in image ui:
when I click on the source image I want to see all the PNG ui's but they are not there.

[image: ui's from the package not list in the source image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**select all images in Assets** and under inspector set **Texture Type** to `Sprite (2D and UI)` and click on **Apply**.
You are done.